# Creating an array that tells if a given number is smaller than 10

Tags: javascript, if-statement, numbers

I am trying to make this work, I don't know what is wrong with it.
It used to work with only 3 variables, when I made it longer it stoped and now I cannot make it work even with only 3. Now it gives me "Undefined Undefined Undefined".
What I want is to crate an alarm in a way that it shows the name of whatever has gone under 10. The fields it is comparing from are calculation fields with the REPEATABLESUM() code.

```
var choice1 = '';
var choice2 = '';
var choice3 = '';
var choice4 = '';
var choice5 = '';
var choice6 = '';
var choice7 = '';
var choice8 = '';
var choice9 = '';
var choice10 = '';
var choice11 = '';
var choice12 = '';
var choice13 = '';
var choice14 = '';
var choice15 = '';
var choice16 = '';
var choice17 = '';
var choice18 = '';
var choice19 = '';
var choice20 = '';
var choice21 = '';
var choice22 = '';
var choice23 = '';
var choice24 = '';

if (NUM($stock_coliblue_24) < 10) {
 choice1 = LABEL('coliblue');
}

if (NUM($stock_absorvent_pads) < 10) {
 choice2 = LABEL('absorvent_pads');
}

if (NUM($stock_micro_filters) < 10) {
 choice3 = LABEL('micro_filters');
}

if (NUM($stock_alkaphotalkalinity) < 10) {
 choice4 = LABEL('alkaphot');
}

if (NUM($stock_ammonia) < 10) {
 choice5 = LABEL('ammonia');
}

if (NUM($stock_calcicol_calcium_hardness) < 10) {
 choice6 = LABEL('calcicol');
}

if (NUM($stock_chloridol_nacl) < 10) {
 choice7 = LABEL('chloridol');
}

if (NUM($stock_free_chlorine_dpd1) < 10) {
 choice8 = LABEL('chlorine_free_dpd1');
}

if (NUM($stock_total_chlorine_dpd3) < 10) {
 choice9 = LABEL('chlorine_total_dpd2');
}

if (NUM($stock_free_copper_n1) < 10) {
 choice10 = LABEL('copper_free_n1');
}

if (NUM($stock_total_copper_n2) < 10) {
 choice11 = LABEL('copper_total_n2');
}

if (NUM($stock_fluoride) < 10) {
 choice12 = LABEL('fluoride');
}

if (NUM($stock_hardicol_total_hardness) < 10) {
 choice13 = LABEL('hardicol');
}

if (NUM($stock_iron_hr) < 10) {
 choice14 = LABEL('iron_hr');
}

if (NUM($stock_iron_mr) < 10) {
 choice15 = LABEL('iron_mr');
}

if (NUM($stock_magnecol_magnesium) < 10) {
 choice16 = LABEL('magnecol');
}

if (NUM($stock_manganese) < 10) {
 choice17 = LABEL('manganese');
}

if (NUM($stock_nitratest_nitrate) < 10) {
 choice18 = LABEL('nitratest');
}

if (NUM($stock_nitricol_nitrite) < 10) {
 choice19 = LABEL('nitricol');
}

if (NUM($stock_phosphate) < 10) {
 choice20 = LABEL('phosphate');
}

if (NUM($stock_potassium) < 10) {
 choice20 = LABEL('potassium');
}

if (NUM($stock_silica) < 10) {
 choice21 = LABEL('silica');
}

if (NUM($stock_sulphate) < 10) {
 choice22 = LABEL('sulphate');
}

if (NUM($stock_sulphitest_sulphite) < 10) {
 choice23 = LABEL('sulphitest');
}

if (NUM($stock_zinc) < 10) {
 choice24 = LABEL('zinc');
}

if (choice1 == null && choice2 == null && choice3 == null && choice4 == null && choice5 == null && choice6 == null && choice7 == null && choice8 == null && choice9 == null && choice10 == null && choice11 == null && choice12 == null && choice13 == null && choice14 == null && choice15 == null && choice16 == null && choice17 == null && choice18 == null && choice19 == null && choice20 == null && choice21 == null && choice22 == null && choice23 == null && choice24 == null) {
  SETRESULT('');
} else {
CONCAT (choice1 + choice2 + choice3 + choice4 + choice5 + choice6 + choice7 + choice8 + choice9 + choice10 + choice11 + choice12 + choice13 + choice14 + choice15 + choice16 + choice17 + choice18 + choice19 + choice20 + choice21 + choice22 + choice23 + choice24);
}
```

Comment: Either it is not javascript or you are missing some function definition

Comment: you may consider a different data structure, either an object or an array.

Comment: Why don't you create an array for storing `choice` instead of creating individual variable ? That's what arrays are for.

Comment: @Eva since this seems to be a [fulcrumapp](http://developer.fulcrumapp.com/expressions/reference/), I can not help you much; I have no experience whatsoever with that framework. But you should definitely include this info into the question, probably even into the title, since there seems to be not tag for fulcrum. The only hint I can provide is about your data structure. `$stock` should be an Object holding the values by the same key you use in `LABEL` then you can write all this as a simple [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Assuming Num is a function which sums up an array (ex.$stock_zinc) of values?Also there is really no point in having choices for each possible product under certain condition. Provide more information for a more concise answer

Comment: I am sorry, I am very new at this, so I am guessing my way to express things is not easy to understand, I am trying my best.

Comment: Weedoze, Nina and Abhishe. Thank you  for your insides but I don't really understand what you are suggesting.
Thomas, I will include that information on the title. Are you saying that the Label should be also a number? 
User1185197, my point is to develop an app for an inventory, which should tell me whether we are running out of any item, the rule is the same for everyone right now, but I would need differents amounts for every item. $stock_whatever is a calculation field, and NUM() is supposed to make sure that the values are being treated as numbers. Is that the information you asked for?

Comment: A decent rule of thumb is that if you are have a bunch of numbered variables like `choice1`, `choice2`, `choice3`, etc., you should start thinking about using an array when the number gets >= 2. If the number gets to 5, you almost certainly should be using an array (perhaps a different data structure, if another one fits better). If you are using variable names for related things like `personName`, `personAddress`, `personHomePhone`, `personCellPhone`, then you should have a good reason why you are not using an Object to hold the related values (e.g. a `person` Object).

Comment: Great!, thanks, I didn't know how Object worked.

Answer (score 0):

user array

```
var choice = [];
var concatStr = "";

if (NUM($stock_coliblue_24) < 10) {
   choice[0] = 'coliblue';
}

if (NUM($stock_absorvent_pads) < 10) {
   choice[1] = 'absorvent_pads';
}

if (choice.length == 0){
   SETRESULT('');
} else {
   concatStr = arr.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Chinito, should that work as it is? I tryied and is giving me nothing, I don't think it recognize <choice.length> , Can be it?

Comment: it should recognize choice.length. maybe there is something wrong with this: NUM($stock_coliblue_24). try to put else statement and assign a value to choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var choice = []; /*Using array notation instead of using 24 separate variables*/

    var concatStr = "";

    if (NUM($stock_coliblue_24) < 10) {
       choice[0] = 'coliblue';          /*storing value in array rather than in variables*/
    }
    ,..
    ,..
    if (NUM($stock_zinc) < 10) {
       choice[23] = LABEL('zinc');
    }

/* Using for loop to iterate through array to check for null values. This is easier than having '==' null check for all 24 variables*/
    for(var i=0;i<24;i++) {
     if(choice[i] == null) {
       SETRESULT('');
       break;
      }
    } 
/*If none of the values are null, then concat the array elements. Array.join is so easier than concatenating 24 string variables.*/

    if(choice.length==24) {
       concatStr = choice.join(" ");
    }
```

Hope this explains.

Comment: It will be a better answer if you will explain your code there!

Comment: Edited my answer with explanation, as I couldn't explain in comments due to  word count limitation.